# inheritance on class attributes (python)

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

Is there a way to accomplish something like this? I work in Python, but I am not sure if there is a way to do it in any programming language...

```
class Parent():
    class_attribute = "parent"

    @staticmethod
    def class_method():
        print __class__.class_attribute

class Child(Parent):
    class_attribute = "child"
```

I know I can't call `__class__` directly. Its just an example, because I would want something like reference to the class itself, because I want the child class to act differently based on its class_attribute.

And then supposed output should be like this:

```
> Parent.class_method()
"parent"
> Child.class_method()
"child"
```

I know the same technique can be accomplish through the instances. But I don't want to create instances, because sometimes the code within the `__init__` method could be long and demanding and if I would want to call `class_method` often, I would have to create plenty of instances used just for this one method call. And because `class_attribute` and `class_method` are static and won't be changed by instances.

Comment: are you talking about simply `static` functions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Er, sounds like you want a classmethod, which not surprisingly is done with the `classmethod` decorator:

```
class Parent(object):
    class_attribute = "parent"

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        print cls.class_attribute

class Child(Parent):
    class_attribute = "child"


>>> Parent.class_method()
parent
>>> Child.class_method()
child
```

Or, as bgporter points out, you can do it directly with the attributes, with no need for the methods at all.

Comment: but considering the documentation: "if a class method is called for a derived class, the **derived class object** is passed as the implied first argument", does it mean that derived class object will be created any way? Because OP says that would like to avoid instance constructon.

Comment: I wanted to call the method, because the code in method might actually do something more complicated then just printing attributes. I though making an easier exmaple would make easier explanation of what I wanted... so @classmethod is a solution

Comment: @Tigran no. A class is itself an object (an instance of its metaclass, actually).

Comment: @DanielRoseman: ah ok, that was actually what I was thinking of. +1

Answer (score 4):

It just works in Python, with or without creating instances:

```
>>> class Parent(object):
...    attribute = "parent"
... 
>>> class Child(Parent):
...    attribute = "child"
... 
>>> p = Parent()
>>> p.attribute
'parent'
>>> c = Child()
>>> c.attribute
'child'
>>> Parent.attribute
'parent'
>>> Child.attribute
'child'
>>>
```